# Execute a pl/sql function with OracleCommand

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, plsql

i have this pl/sql function, the only thing it does is validate that the user exist in the database, if the user exists this returns "Y" but if the user dont exist this return "N", what I want is get the value that I return in pl/sql in c #.

I am using oracle 10g

```
            CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION KRIST.f_Login (userName IN VARCHAR2,
                                                        password IN VARCHAR2)
            RETURN VARCHAR2 
            IS
                CURSOR USERFINDER IS
                    SELECT IdEmpleado
                    FROM EMPLEADO
                    WHERE Usuario=userName
                    AND Clave=password;
                id number;
                returnVal VARCHAR2(1);
            BEGIN
                OPEN USERFINDER;
                FETCH USERFINDER INTO id; 
                IF(id IS NULL) THEN
                    returnVal:='Y';
                    RETURN returnVal;
                END IF;
                returnVal:='N';
                RETURN returnVal;
                CLOSE USERFINDER;
            END;
            /
```

how I can perform this function and get the result in a variable... i have thos code but dont works

```
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("krist.p_login",conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  // use StoredProcedure with Functions as well
                OracleParameter returnVal = new OracleParameter("returnVal",null);
                OracleParameter p_one = new OracleParameter("userName","kristian");
                OracleParameter p_two = new OracleParameter("password", "kristian");
                returnVal.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
                returnVal.Size = 1;
                p_one.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
                p_two.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
                p_one.DbType = DbType.String;
                p_two.DbType = DbType.String;
                returnVal.DbType = DbType.String;
                returnVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                p_one.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                p_two.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p_one);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p_two);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(returnVal);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                String bval = Convert.ToString(returnVal.Value);
                return bval;
```

Comment: do make it easier, use count(*) and see if more than 0 rows returned

Comment: The count is easier and better. SELECT IdEmpleado throws a NO_DATA_FOUND exeption if userName doesn't exists or if password is wrong. SELECT count(*) returns 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code works for me.
NB: Your pl/sql code called the function KRIST.f_Login, but your c# called it krist.p_login
NB2: Your pl/sql code used Varchar2, but your c# used varchar
NB3: I am using Oracle.DataAccess.dll
NB4: I assume your return value buffer size could be 1, but try different sizes.

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

int RETURN_VALUE_BUFFER_SIZE = 32767; 
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
try {
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "KRIST.f_Login";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("returnVal", OracleDbType.Varchar2, RETURN_VALUE_BUFFER_SIZE);  
    cmd.Parameters["returnVal"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("userName", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    cmd.Parameters["userName"].Value = "kristian";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("password", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    cmd.Parameters["password"].Value = "kristian";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    string bval = cmd.Parameters["returnVal"].Value.ToString();
    return bval;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // deal with exception 
} finally {
    command.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Note: Return value must by added as first parameter.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I remember If you are using ODP.NET you need to provide retVal parameter as first.

Something is wrong with ODP.NET and it dosn't bind parameters with provided parameter names but with order of parameters.

So simply change order to:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(returnVal);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_one);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_two);
```

And in my sources I found that return parameter i called "RETURN" (not sure if it counts):

```
OracleParameter returnVal = new OracleParameter("RETURN",null);
```

A ha and one more thing. It will never reach last line - cuase return would terminate execute. Close it as soon as you don't need it anymore.

```
RETURN returnVal;
CLOSE USERFINDER; --<<-- won't close this cursor
```

Comment: ORA-06550: line 1, column 18:

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P_LOGIN'

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

this is the throwing excetion

Comment: Your function in PL/SQL is called F_LOGIN and in .NET you're trying to call P_LOGIN!

Comment: no ok xD....but in one of my attempts to i try to do a procedure with in,out variables and it did not work out but should be p_login

Comment: Adding first the return parameter has worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

ODP.net binds by order by default.  This behavior can be modified with:
    cmd.BindByName = true

Comment: Thanks! you saved me a looot of time!