# Read data table from Oracle DB function in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

**Background**

I'm a .NET dev with very little Oracle experience. A client has given us details of an Oracle function we need to execute against a database on their network. It returns a table of data. I need to use this within ASP.NET.

**Problem**

We have a server which can make the connection. On that server I've installed SQL Plus and am successfully using it to execute the following SQL so I know the connection and function itself are both sound:

```
SELECT FNC_APPTS(PIN_GMC =>'C2331780', PIN_LOCATION =>'RG26 5SW', PIN_DISTANCE => 1000, PIN_PERIOD => 7, PIN_SORT =>'DATE' ) from dual;
```

I've been trying to understand how to use the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` assemly in ASP.NET to use this to populate a `DataTable`. So far I have the following (connection string obfuscated)...

```
string connstring = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=1.1.1.1)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=****)));User Id=****;Password=****;";

using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connstring))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new OracleCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "FNC_APPTS";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("PIN_GMC", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50)).Value = consultantCode;
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("PIN_LOCATION", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50)).Value = location;
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("PIN_DISTANCE", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value = distance;
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("PIN_PERIOD", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value = period;
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("PIN_SORT", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50)).Value = sort;

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dt.Load(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

...but this gives me the error `PLS-00221: 'FNC_APPTS' is not a procedure or is undefined`.

I suspect this is something to do with the "from dual" part of the SQL statement but I'm in the dark as to what this refers to (is it equivalent to a SQL schema or something?). I'd appreciate your advice.

**UPDATE 1**

After some advice from @MethodMan and @kevinsky I tried adding an extra `OracleDbType.RefCursor` parameter, and now the error I'm getting is `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FNC_APPTS'` which would suggest it *is* hitting the function after all. Therefore I assume the original `PLS-00221` error message is more a complaint about my syntax rather than a failure to find the function. Now I'm really stuck and again turn to you, o wise and merciful Stack Overflow community, for guidance...

**UPDATE 2**

After more reading I've now found that if I add a return parameter like this...

```
OracleParameter retVal = new OracleParameter("retVal", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
retVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
command.Parameters.Add(retVal);
```

...then `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` I find that `retVal.Value` is of type `OracleRefCursor`. However, if I then...

```
using (OracleDataReader reader = ((Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleRefCursor)retVal.Value).GetDataReader())
{
    dt.Load(reader);
}
```

... I get the error `ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence`. Feel I'm getting closer here. Does this help at all?

**UPDATE 3**

I believe I'm getting closer. The full error is:

```
ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence
ORA-02063: preceding line from GATE_LINK
```

I now have access to the function body and believe GATE_LINK is a SQL Server database. Since this issue has gone beyond the scope of my original question I have [started a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862878/error-fetch-out-of-sequence-returning-table-from-oracle-function-in-c-sharp-wh) and will link this thread to any answer there if one surfaces.

Comment: in Oracle is your Stored Procedure inside of a `Package` or is it the Stored Procedures Node..? try fully qualifying the name of the Database User for example I have a stored procedure in my Oracle Database located inside of the `OtherUsers` Node named `Humana` so I would do something lite this in the command text 
 `Humana.FNC_APPTS` also you can cut that connection string down to something like this inside of your web.config.. it works because I have tried something like you have and it's nasty to work with

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662497/execute-a-pl-sql-function-with-oraclecommand

Comment: change your connection string and set it up in the web.config file something like this 
`<add name="DbConn" connectionString=" Data Source=YourDatabaseNamev;User Id=yourDBUser;Password=yourdbpassword;" />`

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks, of course I'll config the connection string once this is working. I'm just testing here. Your connection string looks like a SQL Server one though? As for details of the stored procedure, I know very little. I'd assumed since I had a SQL string which I could successfully execute in SQL Plus then I had everything I need to execute and handle returned table in C#. If the function call requires an explicit username then surely the SQL in SQL Plus would also be failing?

Comment: @Avijit Thanks, but can you explain how this link will help?

Comment: nope it works for Oracle I am using Oracle 11.x.x currently and I have used the same format for what you originally have but it's nasty to maintain trust me it works

Comment: What does the function return?  It should return data of type ref cursor or sysrefcursor not a number or a string

Comment: `kevinsky` has indicated something correctly you should have something defined not only in your stored procedure but in your code to return the data example 
`cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_cursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;`

Comment: @kevinsky Thanks guys (@MethodMan too), I'll have to ask the client. All I've been given are connection details, the above example SQL, parameter data types and expected value ranges. However, given my error message it seems the connection isn't even locating the function in the first place... I did just try qualifying the function name with the username we're connecting with but error changes to "identifier 'username.FNC_APPTS' must be declared"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually opened a new question for this issue after zeroing in on the specific cause of my issue. That question and the final answer are here: [Error "fetch out of sequence" returning table from Oracle function in C# where function uses dblink to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862878/error-fetch-out-of-sequence-returning-table-from-oracle-function-in-c-sharp-wh/27863453#27863453)