# Error "fetch out of sequence" returning table from Oracle function in C# where function uses dblink to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle

In C# code I'm trying to load a data table from an Oracle function. The function has a `SYS_REFCURSOR` return type. This is my code that tries to populate a `DataTable dt` using the function:

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connstring))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new OracleCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "FNC_AXA_APPTS";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        OracleParameter retVal = new OracleParameter("PRS", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
        retVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        command.Parameters.Add(retVal);

        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("EG_PARAM", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50)).Value = paramValue;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        using (OracleDataReader reader = ((OracleRefCursor)command.Parameters["PRS"].Value).GetDataReader())
        {
            dt.Load(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

In some cases the Oracle function uses a dblink to a SQL databases. In those cases I'm getting the following exceptions...

```
ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence
ORA-02063: preceding line from GATE_LINK
```

... where `GATE_LINK` is the dblink. My research so far confirms that the issue must lie with the dblink.

We're using the Oracle Data Provider for .NET - is it possible this doesn't support dblink to SQL Server? Or if it does, what can I configure at the SQL end to resolve this?

I should mention that we're connecting to the Oracle DB over a VPN and the connection string uses the following format:

```
"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST={0})(PORT={1}))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME={2})));User Id={3};Password={4};"
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What your function looks like? I thing there is the problem

Comment: Why do you have two different database tags?

Comment: @LalitKumarB If you'd spend some time to read question, you would know that.

Comment: @Reniuz, I read the question. I want to know from OP if he is sure about the problem existing in Oracle or SQL Server. Perhaps, a reply from OP would be good. **Asking for more clarification is always good**

Comment: Then ask if he is sure that problem exists in c#.

Comment: Thanks guys, the issue is resolved. See answer. And @LalitKumarB the problem was in the link within the Oracle function between Oracle and SQL, as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @getsetcode, thanks for the feedback man. Appreciate you coming back and posting your findings. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having spent over a day investigating this I was directed to the answer just 10 minutes after posting my question. Typical!

The answer was found here - https://community.oracle.com/thread/659625 - and all that's required is to wrap the calling code in a transaction. Working code looks like this:

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connstring))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        // Start a local transaction
        using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        {
            // Assign transaction object for a pending local transaction
            command.Transaction = transaction;
            command.CommandText = "FNC_AXA_APPTS";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            OracleParameter retVal = new OracleParameter("PRS", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
            retVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            command.Parameters.Add(retVal);

            command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("EG_PARAM", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50)).Value = paramValue;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            using (OracleDataReader reader = ((OracleRefCursor)command.Parameters["PRS"].Value).GetDataReader())
            {
                dt.Load(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My limited understanding of the solution is that without this a transaction is committed at the SQL Server end which causes the returned cursor to fail in its iteration once passed to the .NET code. If anyone has a better explanation please add to this question.

Comment: After reading [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01002_fetch_out_of_sequence.htm) I thought about possibility that oracle commits transaction before linking to sql-server. That's why I asked for function content. Nice that you shared solution - I was wondering what could it be.

Answer (score -2):

this is valueable solution
using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        {
...
I can do it now, so much tks