# .NET Oracle SQL Command not executing

Tags: sql, .net, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a function that yanks a CLOB column from an Oracle DB that stores rtf strings.

```
public static string GetRTFNoteParsed(string limsNoteNum, string radioEnv)
{
    var rtfNote = "";
    string oradb = GetDBconfig(radioEnv);
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);

    using (conn)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            if (limsNoteNum != null)
            {
                //rtf notes are not stored as plain text. This regex takes it out
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(NOTE_CONTENTS, '\\(fcharset|colortbl)[^;]+;', ''), '(\\[^ ]+ ?)|[{}]', '') FROM LIMS_NOTES WHERE NOTE_ID = " + limsNoteNum;
                //cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NOTE_CONTENTS FROM LIMS_NOTES WHERE NOTE_ID = 86253";
            }
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    rtfNote = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                }
            }

            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e4)
        {
            log.Error("Error with data pulling", e4);
            return (null);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return rtfNote.ToString();

        }
    }
```

I know the problem has something to do with the command, because the commented out command works (but is still formatted in rtf). I know that the command that is causing me issues works just fine in SQL Developer, and so does the commented out one. But when I run it in my .NET application, I get back "ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence." Any ideas?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862878/error-fetch-out-of-sequence-returning-table-from-oracle-function-in-c-sharp-wh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your error `ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence`, but I did get an error `ORA-12725: unmatched parentheses in regular expression` running your code.  The fix to that was to use a C# verbatim string for your query, in other words, to replace

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(......";
```

with

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(......";
```

Using a verbatim string stops C# from processing backslashes in your string, in particular replacing `\\` with `\`.

---

Also, it would be remiss of me if I did not recommend that you use parameterized SQL instead of concatenating strings, as your code is currently vulnerable to SQL injection.  Replace

```
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT ... FROM LIMS_NOTES WHERE NOTE_ID = " + limsNoteNum;
```

with

```
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT ... FROM LIMS_NOTES WHERE NOTE_ID = :note_id";
```

and add the line

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("note_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2, limsNoteNum, ParameterDirection.Input));
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, and thank you for the additional advice. Even after making the command a verbatim string, C# still takes the liberty of making every "\\" into "\\\\" when setting the command text. But the command still works either way, so thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'C# making every "\\" into "\\\\"'.  I see this kind of behaviour if I look at the string value of the SQL text in the VS debugger, but that's how the debugger operates.  Try writing the SQL text to your log instead.