# C# Oracle Function call

Tags: c#, oracle

Can anybody suggest what wrong with this function call. There is no name for the return variable, not sure that makes any issue. This works correctly in pl sql.

---

```
oracle function code:
   FUNCTION GETSTATUS (
   p_param1         in varchar2,
   p_param2    in number,
   p_param3       out varchar2)
   return boolean
   is
   return true;
   END GETSTATUS;
```

---

ODP.Net version - 32 bit  Oraclient10201_win32

C# Code

---

```
var cmd = new OracleCommand("tk_ccc.GETSTATUS ", connweb);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.Parameters.Add("Return_Value", OracleDbType.Char, 1,    ParameterDirection.Output);
var prm1 = new OracleParameter("p_param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20,  ParameterDirection.Input) { Value = "1649983" };
cmd.Parameters.Add(prm1);
var prm2 = new OracleParameter("p_param2", OracleDbType.Int32,  ParameterDirection.Input) { Value = 1 };
cmd.Parameters.Add(prm1);
var prm3 = new OracleParameter("p_param3", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100,  ParameterDirection.Output);
cmd.Parameters.Add(prm1);
var ret = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

Error message:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETSTATUS'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: As best practice functions should return one and only one value, not an out parameter and a value.  Oracle has a boolean value only in PL/SQL.  If your function returned a number it might work.

Comment: Thank you. but this is a shared procedure , and I can not edit just for me.

Comment: Why are you adding a char parameter called `"Return_Value"`?

Comment: there is return value, it does not have any name. but I just assigned a name. do you have any suggestion on that?

Comment: You do cmd.Parameters.Add(prm1);three times. What about .Add(prm2) and prm3? Especially since prm2 is of a different datatype...

Comment: I'd also add that a function that has both an OUT parameter and a return datatype is baaaaadddddd form!

Comment: btw, here is a link to an example of calling a function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662497/execute-a-pl-sql-function-with-oraclecommand

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("Return_Value", OracleDbType.Char, 1,    ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
var prm1 = new OracleParameter("p_param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20,  ParameterDirection.Input) { Value = "1649983" };
I am sorry this is the code, I have just prepared this code not to put any real code online . cmd.Parameters.Add(prm1);
var prm2 = new OracleParameter("p_param2", OracleDbType.Int32,  ParameterDirection.Input) { Value = 1 };
cmd.Parameters.Add(prm2);
var prm3 = new OracleParameter("p_param3", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100,  ParameterDirection.Output);
cmd.Parameters.Add(prm3);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SYS.diutil.bool_to_int procedure can be used to convert bool return value to an integer and use CommandType.Text, this solved my issue.

```
var cmd = new OracleCommand
{
Connection = connweb,
CommandText = "begin " +
":ret_val:= SYS.diutil.bool_to_int(tk_ccc.GETSTATUS(:p_param1,:p_param2,:p_param3)); " +
" end; ",
CommandType = CommandType.Text
};
var returnVal = new OracleParameter("ret_val", OracleDbType.Int32,1);
returnval.Direction=ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(returnVal);
var p_param1 = new OracleParameter("p_param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20);
p_param1.Direction=ParameterDirection.Input;
p_param1.Value = "1649983" ;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_param1);
var p_param2 = new OracleParameter("p_param2", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20);
p_param2.Direction=ParameterDirection.Input;
p_param2.Value = "1" ;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_param2);
var p_param3 = new OracleParameter("p_param3", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 200);
p_param3.Direction=ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_param3);
var ret = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your return value parameter is the problem. It should use `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`, like so:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("Return_Value", OracleDbType.Char, 1, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
```

Comment: even with this change cmd.Parameters.Add("Return_Value", OracleDbType.Char,1, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue); I am getting same error message. ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETSTATUS'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored –

Answer (score 0):

ODP.NET provider does not support `BOOLEAN` data types. You must return a different data type, e.g. INTEGER (`OracleDbType.Byte`) using 0 and 1.