# Using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client to return a value from a function to c#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have the following Function in Oracle:

```
FUNCTION return_test (p_id varchar2) RETURN VARCHAR2
is
   p_return_val VARCHAR2 (500 CHAR) := 'test';
begin  
   return p_return_val;
end;
```

I'm trying to get the value into my c# code as follows:

```
var dbCommand = new OracleCommand();
string retVal;
string Function_query = "PKG_TEST.return_test";
dbConnection = new OracleConnection(ConnString);
dbConnection.Open();


OracleParameterCollection dbParams = dbCommand.Parameters;
dbParams.Add("p_return_val", OracleDbType.Varchar2, System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
dbParams.Add("p_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "123", System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input); 

OracleCommand cmd;
OracleParameter dbAddParam;
cmd = new OracleCommand(Function_query , dbConnection); 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
foreach (OracleParameter dbParam in dbParams)
{
    dbAddParam = (OracleParameter)dbParam.Clone(); // clones all settings
    cmd.Parameters.Add(dbAddParam);
}
retVal = cmd.ExecuteScalar().tostring();
```

The Error while debugging is:

> {"ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer
>   too small\nORA-06512: at line 1"}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662497/execute-a-pl-sql-function-with-oraclecommand

Answer (score 1):

I never worked with `OracleParameterCollection`. Usually I add `Parameters` to `OracleCommand` one by one.

Anyway, try this one:

```
OracleParameterCollection dbParams = dbCommand.Parameters;

dbParams.Add("p_return_val", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 500, null, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
dbParams.Parameters["p_return_val"].DbType = DbType.String; // Maybe this line is not required at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess. However, you must use it for Oracle.DataAccess

dbParams.Add("p_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "123", ParameterDirection.Input); 

string Function_query = "BEGIN :p_return_val := PKG_TEST.return_test(:p_id); END;";
cmd = new OracleCommand(Function_query , dbConnection);     
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add(dbParams);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
retval = cmd.Parameters["p_return_val"].Value;
```

You cannot use method `ExecuteScalar()` on a function call, it is used only for result sets, i.e. `SELECT ...` statements. See [Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleCommandClass.htm#i998581)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Wernfried for your contribution.  I will try it out now.  In the mean time we found this to work:

```
string query = "select PKG_TEST.return_test(:x) from dual";
dbParams.Add("x", OracleDbType.Varchar2, QuoteID, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
var result = (string)dbManager.ExecuteScalar(query, dbParams, CommandType.Text);
```

To me, it seems like its inline SQL which I would always try and avoid, but it worked.  Is there any reason I wouldn't use this?

Comment: Try `begin :p_return_val := PKG_TEST.return_test(:p_id); end;` as query String.

Comment: Rory use comment if you want to comment an answer. And use your question if you give more details. Use the answer only if you answer your question.

Comment: In the end we were overruled and told not to add any inline sql to the c# code.  We had to go back to using the data reader. (I updated my display name)